# FluentValidation Doesn't Work When Using WebApi [Route] Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, model-validation

I successfully implemented FluentValidation in my WebApi project controller that only had one HttpGet method. When I added another HttpGet method, I added route attribute to both methods. i.e. [Route("Method1")] and [Route("Method2")].

Now the ModelState comes back as true regardless of whether I enter any data or not.

Here is my code.

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());

        //FluentValidation
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Menu", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );


    }
}
```

**ValidateModelStateFilter**

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Method1")]
public IHttpActionResult ReadAllMenusByApplication([FromUri] ReadAllMenusByApplicationInput input)
{
        var result = new List<ApplicationMenu>();
        ...
}
```

**Input Object**

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Attributes;

namespace MenuService.Models
{
[Validator(typeof(ReadAllMenusByApplicationInputValidator))]
public class ReadAllMenusByApplicationInput
{
    public ReadAllMenusByApplicationInput() {
        this.ApplicationName = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The MenuSystem name of the application
    /// </summary>
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}

public class ReadAllMenusByApplicationInputValidator : AbstractValidator<ReadAllMenusByApplicationInput>
{
    public ReadAllMenusByApplicationInputValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ApplicationName).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show the controller with both routes and also a sample of the request being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Using this article for reference

[Custom Validation in ASP.NET Web API with FluentValidation](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/custom-validation-in-asp-net-web-api-with-fluentvalidation/)

You seem to have most of what is done in the referenced article.

Check your configuration order.

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Menu", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );

        //FluentValidation
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(config);    
    }
}
```

FluentValidation automatically inserts its errors into the `ModelState`. You should include an error message.

```cs
public class ReadAllMenusByApplicationInputValidator : AbstractValidator<ReadAllMenusByApplicationInput> {
    public ReadAllMenusByApplicationInputValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.ApplicationName).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("The Application Name cannot be blank.");
    }
}
```

The article has some content that is outside of the scope of your question. mainly wrapping the responses but everything else should work for you.